# How to efficiently remove first element from a selection?

Tags: d3.js

I have a page that displays some data using `d3.js`.  Due to the heavy processing load, when the page load it freezes the browser for a few seconds.

I have determined that this "browser locking" behavior is due mostly to a line of the form:

```
selection.attr('d', linefn);
```

...where selection contains around 10K items.

I would like to replace this line with something like

```
function process_rest () {
    if (selection.size() > 0) {
       var next_item = first(selection);  // function first() is hypothetical!
       next_item.attr('d', linefn);
       selection = rest(selection);       // function rest() is hypothetical!
       setTimeout(process_rest, 100);
       return;
    }
    finish_up();
}
setTimeout(process_rest, 100);
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to implement either `first` and `rest`.  My very naive guess would be something like:

```
function first(selection) {
    return d3.select(selection[0][0]);
}

function rest(selection) {
    selection[0] = selection[0].slice(1);
    return selection;
}
```

...but, AFAIK, this is going "behind the API", or at least feels like it.  Is there an "official" (i.e. documented) way to achieve the same result?

EDIT: deleted the `shift` variant (it's safer not to update `selection` until after the processing of the first element has been successfully completed).

Comment: The above (your 'naive guess') may be rather "hacky" but should work, with the one change that your `rest` function should test whether `selection[0]` is empty, and if so slice off the first entry of the outer array.  For using something like this in a more complex situation, be aware that (a) you're be messing up the index numbers of the selection so can't use them and (b) the sliced arrays wouldn't be d3 selections, although your `first` method is handling that by re-selecting the node.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`.each()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each):

```
selection.each(function(d, i) {
  setTimeout(function() { d3.select(this).attr("d", linefn); }, i * 100);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice idea, though in my case setting off a whole bunch of delayed function calls won't work, because there's other stuff to be done that can only happen after all those delayed calls complete.  (That's what the `finish up` bit was supposed to represent in my admittedly confused code; I've fixed it now.)

Comment: You would need to set a separate timeout for triggering you `finish_up` function, and set its delay based on `selection.size()`.

Comment: +1 for Amelia's suggestion. Alternatively, you can simply pass the index of the current element to a function in your style and increment that, checking not to exceed the max index.